# Is it possible to change the "Read More" text in Wordpress depending on post category? i.e. Read Blog Post, Listen to Podcast, View Customer Story etc

Tags: php, wordpress, return

I'm using Wordpress with a plugin called 'Filterable Grid for Divi' by OptimusDivi. Is it possible to change the "Read More" text in the blog grid depending on the post category? i.e. "Read Blog Post", "Listen to Podcast", "View Customer Story" etc.

I have found and tried the JS code to change the standard Divi blog read more to something different but the 'Filterable Grid for Divi' seems to have it's own code and I need the text to change depending on category that the post is in.

I have attached the return code that renders the 'Read More' button but not sure how to get the %4$s that they use for the text to be dynamic depending on the post's category. I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
//Construct button container and button
            return sprintf(
                '<div class="et_pb_jt_filterable_grid_item_button_container">
                    <a href="%1$s" class="et_pb_jt_filterable_grid_item_button et_pb_button%6$s" %2$s%3$s%5$s>%4$s</a>
                </div>',
                esc_url($url),
                ('on' === $grid_item_url_new_window ? ' target="_blank"' : ''),
                ('' !== $grid_item_url_rel ? sprintf(' rel="%1$s"', esc_attr(implode(' ', $grid_item_url_rel))) : ''),
                esc_html($button_text),
                '' !== $custom_icon ? sprintf(' data-icon="%1$s"', esc_attr(et_pb_process_font_icon($custom_icon))) : '',
                ('' !== $custom_icon ? ' et_pb_custom_button_icon' : '')
            );
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, Look at this https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's possible please look at this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More) before you done this

Seeing that you know how it works, now look at how we can make this little invitation to continue reading your post be more inviting

```
<?php
 the_content('your text'); 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks - it's more that I'm not sure what the PHP code is to check the post category.. i.e. If post category ID = 43 then show 'Listen to podcast'.... Else if post category ID = 44 then show 'Read full blog post'.